# How to update "The My site of user is scheuled for deletion" email message in SharePoint 2013

Tags: my-site, alert, mysite, cleanup

The MySite Deletion job is sending an email with subject "The MySite of  is Scheduled for deletion".  This email is sent to the manager and mysite is assigned to the manager.

This email contains a link

```
http://mysite/my/userid
```

The link takes the manager to person.aspx and this page is trying to read information from User Profile Properties, the problem is that the link does not work when the user profile is already disabled/deleted it just gives an error and gives an illusion mysite is already deleted.

Microsoft confirmed that this is an issue and they do not have an ETA on the fix.

I was looking out for an option to update the email link so it adds a link

```
http://mysite/my/userid/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx
```

so that person receiving this email can check the contents (that's what the whole purpose of this email).

I looked at the resource files and xml files and didn't find any information on where this email contents are coming from.  Any idea how the mysite cleanup job is generating this email

Help help help!!!

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the same info. Ever find anything?

Comment: @calorie712 nope,  MS confirmed that this is an issue in the MySite cleanup job,  moreover the email is generated from the code so there is no way we can generate custom email links,  this is still causing a lot of confusions.  Hopefully we get this fixed in the next CU.

Comment: Added answer now the CU has been released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been  fixed with the [September 8 2015 CU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3085481) for SharePoint 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=296 by Eric Shupps. He won't fix the e-mail, but he has a fix for the broken e-mail link.

**Short summary of the fix:**
Include a custom redirect control in the page using the AdditionalPageHead delegate control. This custom redirect control fires before the default redirect control (`PersonalSpaceRedirect`) and thus allows us to redirect to an other page in the users MySite.